# Can a Minecraft PE client connect to a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I setup a Minecraft server, but Minecraft PE will not connect. Are Minecraft PE and Minecraft incompatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Minecraft (normal, original, desktop version) servers are not compatible with Pocket Edition Minecraft clients, and vice versa.

If you want to run a server on your computer that Pocket Edition players can connect to, you will need to use software such as [PocketMine](https://www.pocketmine.net/).

Comment: I installed PocketMine, but I can't connect. Both the server and client are inside the network. One is connected to the router via ethernet while the iPad is on the wifi. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Mod Dragonproxy (See [Tools to connect MCPE to PC](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-mods-tools/2577049-toolconnect-to-any-minecraft-pc-server-using-mcpe)) allows mcpe to connect to java.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Pocket edition is, unfortunately, not compatible with Java Minecraft. I believe the developers hope to have all editions of minecraft compatible with each other by the time Java Minecraft 2.0 comes out, but for now the only Minecraft variant compatible with PE is Windows 10 Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

PE can't connect to PC.  But using pocket mine server you can create a server that supports PE and the BigBrother plugin allows PC clients to connect.